# MySQLSyntaxErrorException when trying to update using java database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I keep getting `MySQLSyntaxErrorException` while updating my DB.

Here is the Stack trace of the error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2788)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2738)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:899)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:737)
>       at Lab6.StudentDB.writeToSQL(StudentDB.java:166)
>       at Lab6.StudentDB.add(StudentDB.java:83)
>       at Lab6.LabWeek6GUI.addJButtonActionPerformed(LabWeek6GUI.java:204)
>       at Lab6.LabWeek6GUI.access$000(LabWeek6GUI.java:16)
>       at Lab6.LabWeek6GUI$2.actionPerformed(LabWeek6GUI.java:68)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Here is my code.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO studentDB (id, name, grade, avg, test1, test2, test3) "
                    + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

stmt.execute(sql);

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
preparedStatement.setString(2, name);
preparedStatement.setString(3, grade);
preparedStatement.setDouble(4, avg);
preparedStatement.setDouble(5, test1);
preparedStatement.setDouble(6, test2);
preparedStatement.setDouble(7, test3);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception comes from `stmt.execute(sql);`, remove that. You appear to be correctly using a `PreparedStatement` after (but your code isn't reached because of the previously mentioned `stmt.execute(sql)` which attempts to run the query with your bind parameters not set).